# .NET Core How to get all timezones + info in an OS-independent way

Tags: c#, .net-core, timezone

I'm building a Discord bot using C# and .NET Core. This bot is supposed to help me convert times between timezones.

Currently, I have this class:

```
class Resources
{
    public static readonly HashSet<string> Timezones = new HashSet<string>(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Select(tz => tz.Id));

    public static TimeSpan idToUTCOffset(string id)
    {
        var t = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(id);
        return t.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

So I have a container which contains all timezone ID's and a function that can convert such an ID to an offset relative to the current UTC time.

The problem with this approach is that the contents of `Timezones` is very dependent on the OS on which the bot is running.
On my windows computer, where I develop and test, I get a nice list with timezones: "Eastern Standard Time", "European Standard Time", etc.
On my raspberry pi, which runs on Raspbian, I get a different list, which appears to be a list of countries/cities which is much larger and much less readable than the list on my windows device.

I would like to get a compact list of all timezones and their details (Start/end of DST or an object that has a function that takes care of DST automatically), like the one I get on my windows device, but then I want it to be OS independent or at least it should work on my raspberry pi.

**Is there a way to get a list of all timezones in a OS-independent way in .NET Core?**

In the end, I want this to work on my raspberry pi, but it would be convenient if it works regardless of the OS.

---

EDIT:
Here's more context to make my question more clear:
The idea of my discord bot is that when somebody asks for the time with a command, the bot will return a table with the time, expressed in all relevant timezones.
Each member in my discord assigns themselves a role, which carries the name of the timezone in which they reside, so I know from every user in which timezone they reside, by the role that they are assigned.
The list needs to be as short as possible, so that the table of relevant times stays as short as possible. There are for example multiple people from Canada in my discord who reside in the same timezone, but not in the same city. If I have a list of each city in Canada, then I get a lot of redundant data in my table.
On top of that, discord supports a very limited amount of roles, so I need the list to be as small as possible.

Comment: If you care about timezones use the [IANA timezone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), not the Windows timezone names. The IANA timezones are the de-facto standard. Instead of `European Standard Time` which frankly doesn't say much, you get `Europe/Berlin` or `Europe/London` that don't change every time a country decides to change timezone rules. [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) is a .NET library that provides far better timezone support than .NET and includes the IANA timezone database

Comment: maybe you simple add that database in your application. I mean there are about 200-250 timezones, you can ship them in xml/json file with your application.

Comment: So, from what I understand, either I have to deal with that enormous list, or I have to create a smaller list by hand? I just hoped there was a way to get a compact list without having to do manual labour...

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter to convert between IANA and Windows Timezone identifiers.

Comment: @AdamG Thank you the link to that library! It does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter), the following will return consistent results on any platform:

- This will give you the current UTC offset of any time zone.  The `id` can be either those from either OS:

  ```
  TimeZoneInfo tz = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(id);
  TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
  ```
- This will list all of the Windows time zone IDs:

  ```
  var list = TZConvert.KnownWindowsTimeZoneIds;
  ```
- This will list all of the IANA time zone names:

  ```
  var list = TZConvert.KnownIanaTimeZoneNames;
  ```

You might also be interested in using [TimezoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) to offer a human-readable list of display names, though it can't yet offer the exact Windows display name that you would see from `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName` on Windows.  That functionality is [on the backlog](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames/issues/50).

Comment: *Full disclosure: I am the author of both libraries.*

Comment: Also - make sure you recognize that the offset may be different for different points in time.  If you haven't yet, read through [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the "Time Zone != Offset" part.  If you're needing the offset to do conversions between time zones, it would be better to use the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime...` methods than to add or subtract offsets yourself.

Comment: That's some good advice! Your library works very well! I'll have a good look at those conversion methods.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint
I fetched all the Window timezoneIds:
**var list = TZConvert.KnownWindowsTimeZoneIds;**

To fetch display names i used these commands.
`string languageCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag;
var displayNames = TZNames.GetDisplayNames(languageCode);`

Applied a loop on Window TimeZoneIds list
`foreach(string a in list){
      Console.WriteLine(displayNames[$"{a}"]);
 }`
It throws an exception **The given key 'South Sudan Standard Time' was not present in the dictionary.**
Can you tell what I am doing wrong here or is it the issue from library?