# Get the Daylight Time Zone in C#

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, .net-core-3.1

I am using .Net 3.1.

I am stuck on what seems to be an easy problem to solve.

In some time zones the offset has recently been changed to diurnal. I use the following function to localize the utc date to the date corresponding to the parameter time zone. It seems that the function does not observe the diurnal offset and continues to get the standard time offset.

```
public static string Localize(DateTimeOffset date, string timeZone, string format = ShortDateShortTime)
        {
            var timeZoneInfo = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(timeZone);
            var localizedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, timeZoneInfo);

            return localizedDate.ToString(format);
        }
```

I pass the following parameters to the function:

- date: `{18/6/2022 0:00:00 +00:00}`
- timeZone: `"Europe/Madrid"`
- format: `"d"`

And the following debug is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXQwn.png)

I am expecting a `+02:00` offset, which is the daylight offset, but I get the standard time offset.

I have seen that there is a SupportsDaylightSavingTime attribute, but I don't know if it is necessary to get the daylight offset.

Comment: Side note: " an easy problem to solve" and date time/time zones???? What made you think that anything related to the subject is "easy"? (rhetoric question... but really think about it).

Comment: https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core How to get all timezones + info in an OS-independent way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023099/net-core-how-to-get-all-timezones-info-in-an-os-independent-way)

Comment: "How can I get the corresponding timeZoneInfo?" - Corresponding to what? TimeZoneInfo represents a time zone, with historic information. A single time zone may sometimes observe daylight saving time, and sometimes observe standard time - but it's still the same time zone. It's really unclear to me exactly what you're asking. A [mcve] which we can run, with your expected results (and an explanation of them) along with the *actual* results, would really help.

Comment: I've changed tags to represent .NET Core 3.1 - there was no such product as ".NET 3.1", and ".NET 3.0" (the previous tag) was a product from 2007. Note that .NET Core 3.1 is also out of support - I'd strongly encourage you to move to .NET 6 or .NET 7.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @quaabaam . The question that have attached it has helped me to know more about timezones, but it doesn't help me to resolve my problem

Comment: Thanks for your comments @JonSkeet . I have editted my question to add more cohesion and clarification. I hope that it I have explained myself well. Any related comments will be helpful. 

We are moving to .Net 6.0 but it will be a long road.

Comment: A [mcve] in a form which I can copy/paste/compile/run, with relevant *console* output rather than a debugger screenshot would be much more useful. It's not clear in what sense you believe you "get the standard time offset" - where your debugger is paused, you haven't executed the `ConvertTime` method call yet. You're looking at the time zone, and its *base* UTC offset of 01:00, which is correct for that time zone. What is the value for `localizedDate`, and what did you expect it to be?